# Configure wget to ignore a specified domain, or treat it differently?

Tags: wget

I'm using `wget` to mirror an old website with all of its
`--page-requisites`. Unfortunately, one of the domains which used to
serve some of these requisites - is now offline. Every time wget tries
to get anything from that domain, it blocks for 10+ seconds until the
connection finally times out.

This issue is substantially exacerbated by the 20 retries. I want to
keep the default retry count at 20, but I know this one particular
domain is never going to respond.

Is there a way to tell wget to ignore that domain entirely, i.e. not
try to fetch anything from there?

If not, can I at least apply different configurations to request from
that domain, for example specify 0 retries for it?

Otherwise, any other suggested solutions for this problem?

Comment: wget man pages talks about an option `--exclude-domains` . Did you try that?

Comment: re-posted it as the answer

Comment: @Sree: where?  I don't see an answer for this question. If you do, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option `--exclude-domains` with wget to exclude specific domains.

From the man page of wget:

```
--exclude-domains domain-list
           Specify the domains that are not to be followed.
```

.